# to use "variable" in function name in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables

Possible to use variable in function name ? (If "yes", so how ?)

```
$name = "john";
  function name_function() {
    //Do something
  }
```

So my function name is going to be `john_function()`

Do you understand what I mean ?

I will to do the better way if I have many functions and I will name clearly like

`john_init()` `john_setup()` `john_save()` `john_clear()`

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Y don't u use switch case.... to call a different function for specific purpose

Comment: Ew what a bad design concept.

Comment: I will to do the better way if i have many functions and i will name cleary like `john_init()` `john_setup()` `john_save()` `john_clear()`

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but have a look at Anonymous functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: @MarkByers You clearly do not understand what is being asked for.  Neither does OptimusCrime.  Closures are a very powerful coding technique.

Comment: Oh many answers , What is the best way to do ? (or to learn) Help me to vote them pls

Comment: I'd say have a look at object oriented programming.

Comment: @clentfort *that* I agree with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading your question and criticism on my answer. I think you're just looking for an OOP implementation

```
class Person {
  public function __construct() // init()
  {
    /* Do something */        
  }

  public function setup()
  {
    /* Do something */
  }

  /* etc */
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
$john = new Person(); // __construct() will be executed here automaticaly
$john->setup();
```

See PHP documentation for more information about Classes & Objects in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/fa/classobj.examples.php

Answer (score 7):

It can't be done quite like you want, which seems to be something like

```
function $name_something(){  }
```

But you can use [Variable Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) like this:

```
function john_something()
{
    echo 'called';
}

$name = 'john';

$functionName = $name . '_something';

$functionName();
```

Not that it is recommended though, there is nearly always a better way of doing it.

Comment: fmpov, this is the correct answer to the question. he didn't ask for object stuff. +1 from me

Answer (score 5):

`eval()` is one way, put I personally think it's icky.

If you enclose your code in a class, you could use:

```
class MyCode {
  public static function __callStatic($functionName, $values)
  {
    // $functionName Receive the name of the function
    // $values       Receives an array with all the parameters
    /* Your code per person here */
  }
}
```

The you could call this functions as follows:

```
MyCode::johnDoesSomething('At home', 'playing with PHP');
```

For more information, see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Comment: This enforces encaspulation of all the code into a class and forces him to use classes. I guess OOP is what he is looking for anyway.

Comment: I don't see what's bad about using OOP. PHP's implementation on this is pretty clean. This example is a complete implementation of overloading, so it should cover everything @l2aelba needs for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use `create_function` to do such a thing.

Please refer to the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)

**EDIT:**

Please check `Ariaan's` reply also. this is more useful

Comment: Your answer simply does not what is asked for. It creates an anonymous function, but he asked for a named not anonymous function. Your answer in fact is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$name = "john";
$f =   "function {$name}_function() {
    //Do something
  }";

eval($f);

john_function();
```

This is an **only solution matching your question**.
And it is a bad solution(**DANGEROUS**), you should better avoid using `eval()` anywhere.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: If its work, But the code look like this, so i dont want to use :(

Thanks anyway

Comment: No, this is the wrong way to do it.  That is *not* what has been asked for.  It is not a reference to a function.  **eval** is also a notoriously insecure and dangerous function to use without careful forethought.

Comment: @itsbruce It is what have been asked by OP. You're right about `eval`

Comment: But I am downvoted. I know that's bad solution, but it matches the question. Exactly matches.

Comment: It surely does exactly what the question asks for. It creates a named function with a variable name. Your answer @itsbruce is wrong. It was not asked for an anonymus function but for a name function that is created.

Comment: @BogdanBurim if you know a solution is dangerous and bad, don't give it.  Or at least accompany it with heavy warnings.

Comment: I agree on the warning parts but why the heck shouldn't he give a right answer? It is better than giving a wrong answer like yours. (Your answer is wrong because it does not address the question asked in this topic, it is the right answer to another question.)

Answer (score 0):

you can't have a function declared in such a manner as to be able to call it in the manner you suggest.

I would have a look at [closures (anonymous functions)](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) - I suspect it will be a elegant solution to your task.